# Best Practices for casting secured content?

Tags: android, google-cast

I am developing a custom receiver app that cast some content to a screen. The content is behind a secured url and I wanted know if there are any guidelines for ensuring that the user is only able to view urls that they are authorized to view.

The solutions I have come up with so far is to place a request from the app to the server that would generate some sort of temporary token that will then be pass along to the receiver app.

The question I have is, is this the best way or is there a more general solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found this from the Google docs with regard to chromecast security:

[Use a secure network with a Chromecast device](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3205704?hl=en)

> We recommend that you use a secure network with your Chromecast
>   device. While it's good security practice in general, using a secure
>   network will also help prevent others from joining your Wi-Fi network
>   without your knowledge and casting content to your TV. Be extra
>   careful whenever you go online using a network you don’t know. Learn
>   more about setting up your home router and Wi-Fi network
>   securely [here](https://www.google.com/safetycenter/everyone/start/safe-networks/).

Comment: noogui Thanks for the link but what I am looking for is guidelines surrounding security between the cast receiver and the backend server. Not between the sender and the receiver.